# Launch MS Word on Client PC to Edit Document on Server

Tags: javascript, office365api

I have a web application(PHP) running on a server which hosts several **DOCX** Documents  (**MS Word** documents)

I want the user (using my application) after choosing any document to be able to:

- open the document  using Microsoft Word installed on his PC
- View the document and edit it.
- save his work, and changes must be committed to the server.

could anyone help me how to do that

ie.

- lunch MS Word on client PC  from JavaScript
- know when the user closes the MS Word application on his PC
- is it necessary to download the file before editing it or I can edit it remotely?

Thanks in advance

Comment: im having lunch right now ;) However nope this isnt possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch Office applications using [Office URI Schemes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn906146.aspx). This would allow you to automatically open the file.

If you want to avoid downloading the file locally, you'll need to implement either [WOPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh622722%28v=office.12%29.aspx) or [WebDav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) on your backend to handle the requests.

A simpler solution would be to use [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/) to push the file into OneDrive. Files in OneDrive have a `WebUrl` property which wires up opening documents in Office for you.