# Button click launch MS Word - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ms-word, header-files

I have an API that downloads the file (Array buffer) from S3 storage and using following code to download the file

```
//Res is the array buffer from S3
import FileSaver from 'file-saver';
var b = new Buffer(res.text, 'base64');

var blob = new Blob([b], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName);
```

Instead of downloading it on local, I want to open the file (PDF, Doc) in a users local MS Word directly when user clicks the button.

I tried looking into the Stackoverflow post

[Launch MS Word on Client PC to Edit Document on Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557763/launch-ms-word-on-client-pc-to-edit-document-on-server)

But this is not clear enough so I am posting this again.

If anyone has any idea that I can tweak with to open MS Word on click from Web app that would be really helpful

```
type: "application/octet-stream"
```

TIA

Comment: You can trigger ms-word from a click using `ms-word`. In an HTML tag it works this way 
`<a href="ms-word:ofe|u|https://your-website.com/your-doc.docx">Open in Word</a>`. The syntax reference is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn906146.aspx

Comment: @steps Wow..that is the 1 that I am looking for. Thank!
Well I have a array buffer of file...Is it also working in case of Array buffer of file?
Thanks